# hadoop cluster with active standby namenode + gap in the edit log

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hdp, namenode

we have ambari cluster , HDP version `2.6.5`

cluster include management of two name-node ( one is active and the secondary is standby )

and 65 datanode machines

we have problem with the standby name-node that not started and from the namenode logs we can see the following

```
2021-01-01 15:19:43,269 ERROR namenode.NameNode (NameNode.java:main(1783)) - Failed to start namenode.
java.io.IOException: There appears to be a gap in the edit log.  We expected txid 90247527115, but got txid 90247903412.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.MetaRecoveryContext.editLogLoaderPrompt(MetaRecoveryContext.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadEditRecords(FSEditLogLoader.java:215)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSEditLogLoader.loadFSEdits(FSEditLogLoader.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadEdits(FSImage.java:838)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.loadFSImage(FSImage.java:693)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:289)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFSImage(FSNamesystem.java:1073)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.loadFromDisk(FSNamesystem.java:723)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.loadNamesystem(NameNode.java:697)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:1001)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:985)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1710)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1778)
```

for now the active namenode is up but the standby name node is down

[image]

regarding to

```
java.io.IOException: There appears to be a gap in the edit log.  We expected txid 90247527115, but got txid 90247903412.
```

what is the preferred solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many causes for this, However, check this [article](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Unable-to-restrat-standby-Namenode/td-p/160067) this should help.

Follow exact steps in exact orders mentioned in article.

In short the error means namenode matadata is **damaged/corrupted**.

Comment: if the edit logs of fsimage is damaged then we should run the command - hadoop namenode -recover   , what you think about?